# How we can make compatible clip-path css property for all browser without svg?

Tags: html, css, clip-path

How we can make compatible `clip-path` css property for all browser without `SVG` ?

Answer (score 1):

`clip-path` isn't supported in IE at all and still not fully supported in modern browsers, so you won't able to achieve that.

See [can I use clip-path](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

[image: clip-path]

Comment: So is there any alternative ? Plz reply soon ..

Comment: <svg id="vlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<polygon fill="#070707" points="0,0 129.267,223.898 258.535,0 "/>
</svg>

<svg id="vlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
 <clippath id="absolute_path">
  <polygon fill="#070707" points="0,0 129.267,223.898 258.535,0 "/>
 </clippath>
</defs>
</svg>   ............ in these both ways clip-path is not working on Firefox

Comment: firefox at the moment only supports `url()`syntax

Comment: I m using this url  clip-path: url("images/v.svg#vlink");

Comment: in your example I don't see that

Comment: Can you give me your skype so i can show you my code ?